# Is there a Tcl equivalent of Perl's shift?

Tags: list, perl, tcl, time-complexity

In Perl/Ruby, one can shift an array (similar to Tcl's list), hence removing the first item in the array, and returning it. Its' runtime is almost constant. I.e., the same for a 2 elements, and 2 million elements.
Is there something similar to that in Tcl? In a way it is the opposite to Tcl's lappend item. Rather than adding 1 to the top, we remove something from the bottom.
The code should look like this:

```
set k [ list 1 2 3 ]
puts [ shift k ]
> 1
puts [join $k ","]
> 2,3
```

I can do this in a proc, of course:

```
proc shift {list_name} {
   upvar $list_name listy
   set ret [lindex $listy 0]
   set listy [lrange $listy 1 end ]
   return $ret
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: There is a [page about lshift](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8177) in the tclers wiki.  Compared to your version, the use of `lreplace` is said better in performance,  according to [Tcl gems page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/918).

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest I got for what I need.

Comment: After a look into meta Stack overflow, and because you find this was the closest for what you need, and despite other quality answers, I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As said in my comment)

There is a [page about lshift](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8177) in the tclers wiki. Compared to your version, the use of lreplace is said better in performance, according to [Tcl gems](http://wiki.tcl.tk/918) page.

```
proc lshift listVar {
    upvar 1 $listVar l
    set r [lindex $l 0]
    set l [lreplace $l [set l 0] 0]
    return $r
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code clocks in right between your code and the `lreplace` code abendhurt mentioned. The main advantage of this is that it is a little more compact and readable than both.

```
proc shift list_name {
    upvar 1 $list_name listy
    set listy [lassign $listy ret]
    return $ret
}
```

Documentation:
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Try `lassign`:

```
set k {1 2 3 4}
set k [lassign $k i]
puts $i; # 1
puts $k; # 2 3 4
```

For better performance, you can unset the list while manipulating it:

```
set k [lassign $k[unset k] i]
```

With some upvar magic, you can write your own shift:

```
proc shift {list} {
    upvar 1 $list l
    set l [lassign $l result]
    return $result
}
# Usage:
set myList {1 2 3 4}
puts [shift myList]; # 1
puts $myList; # 2 3 4
```

Comment: Great minds think alike? :) This answer doesn’t add very much to mine.

Comment: Yeah, true. Maybe I could add some kind of unset magic (no shared object), but well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `struct::list`:

```
package require struct::list
set li {1 2 3 4}
::struct::list shift li; # li is now {2 3 4}
```